# Django - Accessing relational database in view

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

This is my forms.py:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    PET_CHOICES = (
    ('none','---'), ('dog', 'Dog'),
)

    username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password1 = forms.CharField()
    birthdate = forms.DateField(widget=extras.SelectDateWidget)
    pet = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PET_CHOICES)
```

This is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class UserExtended(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    pet = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

As you can see, this model extends the default Django User model. Now, this is my view which registers users:

```
def registerView(request):
    form = RegistrationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
                password=form.cleaned_data['password1'],
                email=form.cleaned_data['email']
            )

            user.userextended_set.pet=form.cleaned_data['pet']
            user.userextended_set.age=form.cleaned_data['birthdate']

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

I'm wondering, is this part of my code correct?

```
user.userextended_set.pet=form.cleaned_data['pet']
user.userextended_set.age=form.cleaned_data['birthdate']
```

With the two lines above, I am trying to add to the UserExtended model which has a ForiegnKey with User. I think I am doing something wrong because after the user is created and I authenticate and log the user in using the functions

```
authenticate()
```

and

```
login()
```

provided by django, and if I place this in my template which Django redirects to after logging in

```
<p>your pet is {{ user.userextended_set.pet }}</p>
```

it does not display another for

```
{{ user.userextended_set.pet }}
```

. It just says:

```
your pet is
```

. Any idea why it does not display anything? {{ user.userextended_set.pet }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is,

`user.userextended_set` returns a `RelatedManager` type. So, you cannot do a simple `.pet` would not work.

Now, looking at your models, i am *assuming* you intend `UserExtended` to a `OneToOneField`, rather than a `ForeignKey`. As long as you can manage the (non) creation of duplicates, you are just fine.

Now, coming back to your issue:

You can do

```
user_extended = user.userextended_set.all()[0]
#Or if you are sure it is a unique relationship,
#user_extended = user.userextended_set.get()
#Note - this would raise error if MultipleObjectsReturned, or DoesNotExist

user_extended.pet = form.cleaned_data['pet']
user_extended.age = form.cleaned_data['age']
```

Also, in the template,

```
{{ user.userextended_set.0.pet }}
```

Or even this:

```
{% for u_e in user.userextended_set.all %}
    {{u_e.pet}}
{% empty %}
    Not found
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: also, what exactly do you mean by "As long as you can manage the (non) creation of duplicates, you are just fine."?

Comment: I mean you should ensure that your application does not allow the creation of `UserExtended` object more than once for any given user.

Answer (score 2):

`userextended_set` is actually a manager, not a `UserExtended` object, because you have a `ForeignKey` in `UserExtended`, which indicates that a `User` could have multiple `UserExtended` objects. This probably isn't what you want — you probably want to use a `OneToOneField` instead.

Comment: when I change it to a OneToOneField and then create a new user, it gives me an error saying "AttributeError at /register/" (which calls the registerView). The error says "'User' object has no attribute 'userextended_set'". The traceback refers to the line in registerView which says "user.userextended_set.pet=form.cleaned_data['pet']".. Any idea why it is doing this?

Comment: Right, in a `OneToOneField`, you'd reference the field as `user.userextended`.